# Structure array writing to text file

Tags: c++, struct, writetofile

I am having problems with file writing function for my structure array. I am getting errors, that  `could not convert 'cars[n]' from 'car' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'`

I am little bit confused with file writing, maybe someone could explain or give me some hints how to make my writing function work?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

#define N_CARS 2

struct car{
    string model;
    int year;
    double price;
    bool available;
    }cars [N_CARS];


void writeToFile(ofstream &outputFile, string x )
{
    outputFile << x << endl;
}


    int main ()
{
  string mystr;
  string mystr2;
  string mystr3;
   int n;

  for (n=0; n<N_CARS; n++)
  {
  cout << "Enter title: ";
  getline (cin,cars[n].model);
  cout << "Enter year: ";
  getline (cin,mystr);
  stringstream(mystr) >> cars[n].year;
  cout << "Enter price: ";
  getline (cin,mystr2);
  stringstream(mystr2) >> cars[n].price;
  cout << "Choose availability: ";
  getline (cin,mystr3);
  stringstream(mystr3) >> cars[n].available;
}
   ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("bla.txt");
    for (n=0; n<N_CARS; n++)
    writeToFile(outputFile, cars[n]);
    outputFile.close();

   system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Am I getting it right that `outputFile << x << endl;` will write to file my whole struct fields?

Comment: Sure the error message isn't related to this bug: `writeToFile(outputFile, cars[n]);`?

Comment: compiler shows that issue is there. But how I can change it?

Comment: Check the parameter types of your function again. Can `Car` be converted to `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I getting it right that outputFile << x << endl; will write to file my whole struct fields?

The following:

```
void writeToFile(ofstream &outputFile, string x )
{
    outputFile << x << endl;
}
```

has absolutely nothing to do with your struct or your fields.  It writes a string.

The following:

```
writeToFile(outputFile, cars[n]);
```

invokes a function which accepts an `std::string`, and tries to pass a `car` to it.  That's not going to work.

You have a number of options:

- Output every single member of your structure by yourself, using `<<`.
- Overload the `<<` operator for your structure, so that you can actually do `outputFile << mycar`, where `<<` will be invoking your overloaded operator. (This is the best option.)
- Make your structure convertible to `std::string`.  This is going to turn around and bite you later, because at some point you will inevitably need to read your structure from a stream, and then you are going to have to make your structure also convertible *from* string, which means string parsing, which is ugly and error-prone business.